# How to stop Excel switching to horizontal scroll?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, mouse, scrolling, microsoft-office-2016

This has been driving me mad for years. I don't know if it's from Excel, Windows, or the mouse itself (Sharkoon Fireglider)... but it only happens in Excel.

If the mouse is moved to the right of the workbook the mouse wheel switches from vertical scroll to horizontal - very easy to accidentally trigger especially with frozen columns.

An overlay appears indicating the partition between vertical and horizontal scrolling, and a wheel icon when the mouse is in 'horizontal territory'.

I only want to scroll vertically!

Please help

[horizontal scrolling overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Gy7O.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partial possible solution is to limit the scrolable area. To do so, on the Developer tab, click on properties then on SCrollableArea, enter the range. From now on when you try to go beyond the set limit, you will be taken back to area you defined.

[image]

However, this only work for a worksheet, and you will have to set it for every single worksheet (which might be inconvenient). Or you can use a macro to set it when you open workbooks.

**Edit:** From this [article](https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2013/10/03/prevent-scrolling-on-excel-worksheet/#:%7E:text=Even%20if%20a%20worksheet%20is,manually%20or%20with%20a%20macro.) also explaining the process above, there is a code of macro to accomplish setting up the scrollable area for a workbook. You need to add a Module and add the following code to it.

```
Sub SetAllScrollAreas()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.ScrollArea = ws.UsedRange.Address
Next ws
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    SetAllScrollAreas
End Sub
```

As an aside note, To stop Showing the horizontal scroll bar:

Open Excel Options (File -> Options), go to Advanced, then "Display options for this workbook". Uncheck "Show horizontal scroll bar".

[image]

Comment: The first option of limiting the scroll area still allows the mouse to switch to horizontal scrolling... but your second suggestion of disabling the horizontal scroll bar completely does the trick! Even at the expense of losing the horizontal bar I'll take it! Thanks

Comment: @Vok On mine, it goes/scrolls horizontally, but when the scroll stops (or I click anywhere on the worksheet), it goes back to the allowed area. How does it performs on your side?